# Bootstrap 4 collapsed navbar not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem with collapsed navbar in Bootstrap4.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse fixed-top bg-inverse">
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="  navbar-brand" href="#myCarousel">
        <img src="image/logo.svg" height="50">
      </a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav nav mr-auto">
           <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#2"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.show">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#3"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.show">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#4"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.show">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </nav>
```

Of course ihave added right id to another elements, like:

```
<div class="container marketing" id="2">
```

Menu doesn't work. When i click on element of navbar, menu close but doesn't move to right site.

When delete collapse's attributes:

```
data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.show"
```

menu doesn't close on click but move to right site.

Thanks :)

Comment: could you create jsFiddle or a working demo?

Comment: Take https://jsfiddle.net/x5j5gudh/2/

"Contact" is whitout collapse and working fine, check it :)

Comment: I did not understand you clearly, could you be more specific about what you want?

Comment: I want mobile collapsed navbar. 

test, when you click on "About" in mobile navbar is closed but not move to right page. But if you click on "Contact" (without collapse atribute) it move to right page.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse fixed-top bg-inverse">
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="  navbar-brand" href="#myCarousel">
        <img src="image/techNET.svg" height="50">
      </a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav nav mr-auto">
           <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#2"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.show">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#3"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse.show">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#4">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
       
      </div>
    </nav>
```